# React Native show different component when keyboard show

Tags: react-native

When the keyboard show, we're going to have `button A` wrapped around the `keyboardAvoidingView` and `button B` when the keyboard is down.

`Manifest` is set to `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, so `button A` is also raised.

Android doesn't have `keyboardWillShow`, `keyboardWillHide`, so I used `keyboardDidShow`, `keyboardDidHide` to hide and show the components, but it works unnaturally as it is treated with Did instead of `keyboardWillShow`, `keyboardWillHide.

Is there any other way but to give `onFocus`, `onBlur` to input?